# how to merge two text files and create another text file and load in HIVE through shell script?

Tags: shell, hive

I have a location on the server, where I have 2 files in txt format. We need to automate the process wherein following are the conditions:
1)Either one of the files would be available for loading to the HIVE table.
2) both the files could also be available to load. But in this case, we need to merge both the files into a single file and then load to the HIVE table.

Based on the requirement, below is the code that I have come up with. But it is not working:

```
    #!/bin/bash
    cd <path_to/source_files/>
    file1="file1.txt"
    file2="file2.txt"
    #file3=$file1 + $file2


    if [$file1 and $file2 ]
    then
cd <path_to>/source_files/
            echo "Loading both the files"
cat file* > merge.txt
    hive << EOF
    use sprint1;
    TRUNCATE TABLE sprint1.SET;
    LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH '<path_to>/source_files/merge.txt' INTO TABLE SET;
    INSERT INTO TABLE hist_SET select * from SET;
    EOF
    rm -rf ltd_al_merge.txt
    fi

    if [ -f "$file1" ]
    then
            echo "$file1 existing in source."
    hive << EOF
    use sprint1;
    TRUNCATE TABLE sprint1.SET;
    LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH '<path_to>/source_files/file1.txt' INTO TABLE SET;
    INSERT INTO TABLE hist_SET select * from SET;
    EOF

    else
            echo "$file1 NOT EXISTS in the source"
    fi

    if  [ -f "$file2" ]
    then
     echo "$file2 existing in source "
    hive << EOF
    use sprint1;
    TRUNCATE TABLE sprint1.SET;
    LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH '<path_to>/source_files/file2.txt' INTO TABLE SET;
    INSERT INTO TABLE hist_SET select * from SET;
```

When executing the code doesn't understand the very first "if". Please let m eknow my mistake.

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by "the code doesn't understand the very first if"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to check the presence of the file, you have to use like below

```
if [[ -f $file1  && -f $file2 ]]
then
echo "file1 - exists"
echo "file2 - exists"
fi
```

Note the space around "[[" and "]]". They are exes.. so they should be surrounded by spaces.